# Sum of two Bernoulli random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is from my actuarial study manual. I am having trouble finding the distribution of X+Y where X and Y are two Bernoulli random variables, where X consists of n Bernoulli trials, and Y consists of j Bernoulli trials.

What I do know: $f_X(X;p)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ for X=0 or 1. 
I also know that $M_X(t)=1-p+pe^t$ and that for any iid $X_1,..,X_n$, we have that if $Z=X_1+...+X_n$, then 
$M_Z(t)=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}M_{Xi}(t)$
I was trying to use the mgf method to find the distribution (by finding a recognizable distribution with the mgf). However, I am not having much luck

Comment: Same parameter $p$ for $X$ and $Y$? If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $Z=X+Y$ is Binomial $(n+j,p)$. If the success parameter is different then I don’t think it’s straightforward.

Comment: @KaboMurphy $n$ IID Bernoulli’s is Binomial distributed. OP states all but the independence explicitly.

Comment: @KaboMurphy It says $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables, but then goes on to say "$X$ consists of $n$ Bernoulli trials" and $Y$ consists of $j$ Bernoulli trials. It is not clear whether $X$ and $Y$ are to be Bernoulli or binomial here - and actually, it is not clear whether said Bernoulli trials are independent, which would be necessary for a binomial distribution to be appropriate.